# Access to liquibase.properties with war

Tags: java, liquibase

Let's assume I have 2 maven modules: **datasource** which is packaged as *jar* and **portal** which is packaged as *war* and it depends on **datasource**.

I'm using Liquibase in my project and *liquibase.properties* is stored in **datasource** module resources.

Now I want to run liquibase with command line using my config file. I'm trying to do it with command:

```
java -jar liquibase.jar \
      --classpath=portal.war \
      --defaultsFile=liquibase.properties 
     rollback
```

But I get error from Liquibase:

```
Errors:
  --url is required
  --changeLogFile is required
```

It seems that liquibase does not see my properties file in nested *jar*. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm doing wrong?

Apparently ... liquibase is capable of finding and loading a properties from the classpath.  Here's the code that attempts to open the property file as a resource:

```
    try (InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader()
             .getResourceAsStream(potentialPropertyFile.getAbsolutePath())) {
        if (resourceAsStream != null) {
            parsePropertiesFile(resourceAsStream);
        }
    }
```

If you don't supply an *absolute* resource path, the code is going to attempt to resolve the path in the context of a current directory in the host file system.

(This is from the HEAD Liquibase source code as of 2017-08-29:

- https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/commit/ff5d7842ab73b90642582f27fddf3eb91088a863

I think this behavior is a bug ....)

---

Workaround:  Change the command line option to specify the *absolute* resource path for your properties file resource.